# What is -Osize build setting for Swift in Xcode 9.3?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Today I update my Xcode from 9.2 to 9.3

So there is mention that **Swift Compiler Adds new code optimization, enable with the -Osize Build setting**.

[image]

Comment: It's exactly what it says on the box: it optimizes size of the compiled code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [release notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/Chapters/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001051-CH1-DontLinkElementID_1)

> Added an option to optimizing by size (-Osize) to the Optimization Level for the Swift compiler to the Build Settings pane of the Project editor. When this mode is selected the Swift compiler minimizes the size of compiled code. (36887476)
>
> The choice for compiling Swift code by file or by module moved from the Optimization Level setting to Compilation Mode, which is a new setting for the Swift compiler in the Build Settings pane of the Project editor. Previously this choice was combined with others in the Optimization Level setting. Compiling by file enables building only the files that changed, enabling faster builds. Compiling by module enables better optimization. (36887476)

Comment: Really weird... so basically `-Owholemodule` is "optimize for speed" and `-Osize` together with compilation mode set to `wholemodule` is "optimize for size" o_0